# Downloading multiple files using FTP in C#

Tags: c#, ftp

I need to write a routines that downloads a given directory on the server completely - all the files and directories in it.

Right now I have a routine that lists dir content

```
public List<string> GetListOfFiles(string serverPath)
        {
            List<string> files = new List<string>();
            try
            {

                FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://" + serverPath);               
                request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_domain + "\\" + _username, _password);
                request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;               


                FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

                string line = reader.ReadLine();
                while (line != null)
                {
                    files.Add(line);                    
                    line = reader.ReadLine();
                }
                response.Close();

            }           
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)ex.Response;
                string exMsg = string.Empty;

                switch (response.StatusCode)
                {
                    case FtpStatusCode.NotLoggedIn:
                        exMsg = "wrong username/password";
                        break;   


                    default:
                        exMsg = "The server is inaccessible or taking too long to respond.";
                        break;
                }   


                throw new Exception(exMsg);
            }
            return files;

        }
```

The issue is that I get the list of files and directories...so something like

file1.dll
file2.dll
dir1Name

Is there a way to make a distinction between a file name and a directory name when listing it? Like a flag?

Comment: The response returned by `ListDirectory` is not standardized and can vary based on the software the server is running.  Because of this, there isn't a good way to tell directories from files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the returned information is really a function of your FTP server, not the framework.

You can [`ListDirectoryDetails`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequestmethods.ftp.listdirectorydetails.aspx) instead of `ListDirectory`, which should provide you much more detailed information (including whether each file is a directory or a file), but would require special parsing, as its format, too, is dependent on the FTP Server.